# Courier configure script failing to produce a Makefile

Tags: linux

The "INSTALL" file for Courier Mail Server 1.0.6 specifies that the `./configure` script will automatically select the correct settings for its parameters.  Included below is a portion of the "config.log" file for your consideration.  The portion in the black rectangle indicates the error (at least the only one I have found so far).   This is most likely why the `./configure` script is not producing a makefile.
[image]

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). In addition to that, the image is really hard to decipher due to the choice of colour scheme.

Answer (score 2):

The portion of `config.log` you posted is fine; `./configure` tries a number of ways of determining the compiler version, and some of those fail, but that’s not a problem.